# Laravel show data from database and convert to json

Tags: php, json, laravel

i'm trying show data from database on laravel, but don't show anything in view blade. Every group hasMany lapangan(eng: court) data

```
$groups_resource = Groups::all();
  $groups = [];
  foreach($groups_resource as $group)
  {
    $g = new Groups();
    $g->id_group = "Group_".$group['id_group'];
    $g->name = $group['nama'];
    $g->expanded = true;
    $g->eventHeight = 25;
    $g->children = array();
    $groups[] = $g;

  $lapangan_resource = Lapangan::with('groups')->orderBy('nama')->get();
  foreach($lapangan_resource as $lapangan)
  {
    $l = new Lapangan();
    $l->id_lapangan = $lapangan['id_lapangan'];
    $l->name = $lapangan['nama_lapangan'];
    $g->children[] = $l;
  }
  }
    return json_encode($groups);
```

output

```
[{"id_group":"Group_1","name":"Lapangan Badminton","expanded":true,"eventHeight":25,"children":[]},{"id_group":"Group_2","name":"Lapangan Tenis","expanded":true,"eventHeight":25,"children":[]}]
```

> There is no children output for every id_group
>   .what i want

```
{"id":"group_1","name":"Indoor","expanded":true,"eventHeight":25,"children":[
    {"id":"1","name":"Court 1"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Court 2"},
    {"id":"3","name":"Court 3"},
    {"id":"4","name":"Court 4"}]},
  {"id":"group_2","name":"Outdoor","expanded":true,"eventHeight":25,"children":[
    {"id":"11","name":"Court 5"},
    {"id":"12","name":"Court 6"},
    {"id":"13","name":"Court 7"},
    {"id":"14","name":"Court 8"}]}
]
```

Any idea?

Comment: I do not see anything you are outputting ? No Echo or print or blade template output.

Comment: i put $datagrup variable to javascript function. Now i got error 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'. is there are mistake from $datagrup?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a response in JSON format than you can use [`json()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses) method as:

```
return response()->json($datagrup);
```

OR

To convert a model to `JSON`, you should use the [`toJson`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json) method. Like `toArray`, the `toJson` method is recursive, so all attributes and relations will be converted to JSON:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

return $user->toJson();
```

Comment: If i use query builder, there are some different?

Comment: Didn't get you?

Answer (score 0):

Even though, you code seems to really fixed... I still feel the below code should work for you :)

I am not sure what exactly you mean by `$datagroup[] = $dataresource`? Do you want to add `datagroup to dataresource` or `dataresource to datagroup`... Your code shows something and the output desired is something else.

```
$datagroup = array_map(function($groups) use ($scheduler_resources) {
              return [
                'id' => $group['id_group'],
                'name' => $group['nama'],
                'expanded' => true,
                'children' => $scheduler_resources->map(function($resource) {
                                return [
                                  'id' => $resource->id_lapangan,
                                  'name' => $resource->nama_lapangan,
                                ];
                              }),
                'eventHeight' => 25
              ];
             }, $scheduler_groups);

echo json_encode($datagroup);

// or
// return response()->json($datagroup);
```

Note :- Please ensure `$scheduler_resources` is different for each `$datagroup`

Comment: I got error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
May i change -> instead of ['id_group'] ?

Comment: @Ferdy Which one of your variables is an object and not an array?

Comment: @Ferdy Can you do `dd($scheduler_groups, $scheduler_resources)` and edit your question so I know what is in those variables?

Comment: $groups is an array
$scheduler_group and $scheduler_resource i declare for call data from database

Comment: @Ferdy `$scheduler_resource` is a collection or JSON Object? If it is a collection, please try my answer again... I edited it.

Comment: $scheduler_resource is a collection